# What is the difference between xtightvncviewer and vncviewer?

Tags: ubuntu, tightvnc

What is the difference between xtightvncviewer and vncviewer?

These two commands seem to do the same thing on Ubuntu and answer to the -version option as TightVNC Viewer version 1.3.9.

Comment: Trying `vncviewer` on Kubuntu suggests `xtightvncviewer` as one of the packages containing it. Perhaps an alias used by several packages, so a `vncviewer` can be used without needing a specific VNC package, just one of several available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`vncviewer`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/vncviewer) is a **virtual** package that is **only** provided by `xtightvncviewer`.

They're (currently) the same thing.

To double-check, let's look at the files themselves:

```
oliver@ubuntuDesktop:~$ ls -lha /usr/bin/vncviewer 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 2012-04-07 14:35 /usr/bin/vncviewer -> /etc/alternatives/vncviewer
oliver@ubuntuDesktop:~$ ls -lha /etc/alternatives/vncviewer
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 2012-04-07 14:35 /etc/alternatives/vncviewer -> /usr/bin/xtightvncviewer
```

So, `vncviewer` is just a placeholder in the system for whatever package you install that provides *a vncviewer*. In this case there is only one option `xtightvncviewer`.

There are several virtual packages. They are defined by the **`Provides:`** setting defined in other packages. The best list of virtual packages I found is this one: http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/virtual-package-names-list.txt

Virtual packages are very useful for package maintainers. You can create your own package and say "*If you want to use this package, you'll need another package that **provides** an `ftp-server`.*" The package doesn't care which one, as long as you installed a package that  **provides** an `ftp-server`.